# Typing in a URl without adding the port

Tags: url, lighttpd, ports

I have set up a site with lighttpd. The hosting works fine, but I have to add a port to the end of the URL otherwise I get a blank page. Is there any way I can type the URL and get the page without the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a port is not specified on the URI, port 80 is assumed (as stated in [RFC 2616, item 3.2.2](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.txt)).

Therefore, to get rid of the port - make sure your web server is listening on port 80.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to use ports other than 80 without typing the port?

Comment: No, unless HTTPS is used, and then you should listen on port 443 (and enable a valid SSL connection).